# Get subgraph connecting two resources

Tags: dbpedia

What is the best strategy using SPARQL queries over DBpedia to retrieve the subgraph that connects two resources ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for a sequence of Q nodes connected by P edges, is that correct? It's ugly, but you could look for all graphs of length 1, then of length 2, then of length 3, and so on.

Comment: No way, if a triplestore doesn't provide the short path function. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916584/7879193. In theory, one should be able to write `DESCRIBE ?u ?p ?v` etc.